# How to change state when a function runs using ui.router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a search service in my application which is using angularjs. I'm using ui-router too. Now the problem I'm facing is - 
When a user types on the input (suppose) - xyz and hits enter, I dont know how to change the state. 
Like from - abcd.com, he/she should move to abcd.com/search?q=xyz
which will be a different page altogether. 
I have never worked on search before so please help me figure it out.

On the basis of comment below i decided to first try state.go for changing my state when clicked on a button -

Heres my controller -

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($state){
var search = this;
search.changeState = function () {
$state.go('abcd');
```

};
});

here's my html -

```
<body ng-app="mySearch" ng-controller="myCtrl as app" >


        <button ng-click="app.changeState">asd</button></div>

<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Still the url isnt changing

Comment: `ng-submit` + `$state.go({/* params*/})` would get you started.

Comment: I have  var search = this;
  search.changeState = function () {
    $state.go('abcd'); in my controller and on page i used a button, still the page isnt transitioning

Comment: read the $state docs... need to pass object. Show your routing config in question. Do you have params configured in state url's in config? Hard to help if you don't post some code

Comment: Would this be enough ? I'm trying to test state.go , havent used it before

Comment: where's your routing configuration...have you created it? You need params in url per the documents so when you pass object to `go()` it can be compiled in the url. Think you need to go through some angular routing tutorials

Comment: i have the config , its working  fine when i use ui-sref, for state.go, i think its the stateparams that i gotta use, if thats what you mean? Anyway, thanks